# Разграничение доступа на странице используя роли во flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Пользуюсь flask-ом с недавнего времени и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Нужно,например,сделать отдельные участки страницы,которые будут видны только админу.

Соответственно, `roles_required()`,`roles_accepted` не подходят, а проверять каждый раз через `if` - совсем не оптимально. 
Может быть есть какой-либо другой способ реализовать это?

Comment: Лично я как раз проверяю через `if` )

Answer (score 0):

FlaskSecurity очень достойное решение. Попробуйте использовать в своем проекте. Хорошая документация

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/